# Class added twice for no particular reason

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a carousel with jQuery, which works with active, inactive and non-specific classes. The first element of the list is made active by simply putting the "active" class. I execute this code to go to the next item, which should remove the "active" class from the current item, add it to the next, add the "inactive" class to the current so it has time to go through the transition and then remove the "inactive" class so that the next time it is executed, it can use the "inactive" class in the selector without selecting two objects after .5 seconds.

However, after .5 seconds, not only is the "inactive" class removed, but an "active" class appears out of nowhere. What in the world am I doing wrong?!

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
  <a class="back" onclick="bannerBack()"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
  <a class="next" onclick="bannerNext()"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="featured-item active">...</div>
    <div class="featured-item">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Function**

```
var ready = true;
function bannerNext() {
   if (ready) {
      ready = false;
      $(".featured-item.active").addClass("inactive");
      $(".featured-item.inactive").removeClass("active");
      if ($(".featured-item.inactive").is(".featured-item:last-child")) $(".featured-item").first().addClass("active");
      else $(".featured-item.inactive").next().addClass("active");
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".featured-item.inactive").removeClass("inactive");
        ready = true;
      }, 500);
   }
}
```

**Edit:** Shortened HTML code because the content inside has no function in the code.

Comment: You may want to checkout the [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function, which would make it easier to, well, toggle those classes on and off. You've got some issues with your selectors and where classes are applied. You're probably better off using just `active` instead of trying to keep track of both that and `inactive`...

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was running a countdown timer alongside the code which would activate the first element every second, thanks for providing possible solutions.